# How can I determine if an Excel workbook is open on local machine given that there may be multiple instances of Excel running?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to modify an Excel file that may or may not be open on the local machine. The machine may have multiple instances of Excel running, or the file may be open on the network (in which case no modification would be made).  Based on my understanding, `getObject(file_path)`, will either:

1. grab the open instance of the workbook if the file is open on the local machine
2. open the file in an already running Excel session if the file is not open, or
3. open the file in a new Excel session if none are running.

In all 3 instances, I'm able to manipulate the document in certain ways.  However, if I use `getObject(file_path)` and the file is not already open, I'm having trouble calling the application object of the workbook. Any line with `getObject(file_path).application` gives me the error:

> "Object required: 'application.Evaluate(...)'"

in instances where the Workbook is not already open.

I've worked around this limitation by first testing if any instances of Excel are open; if none are, then I manually create an instance and then open the workbook using `application.Workbooks.Open(to_filename,UpdateLinksCode)`.  The code below works in scenarios 1 and 3.  I could try to open the workbook using "`Workbooks.open`" in every scenario; however it's important that at the end of the execution, the Excel instances and open workbooks are the same as when the script started (so, in effect, I probably need to determine whether I'm in scenario 1 or 2).

For context, the program below is meant to update pivot table ranges in Excel 2007. To test, you need a workbook with a pivot table and set to _filename  as the file path and sheet_name to be the name of the sheet with the pivot data.

```
Dim UpdateLinksCode, UpdateLinks, destsheet, excel_version, comma_delimit, tab_delimit, t, filename, sheet_name, to_filename, safepath, replacesheet, fso, sourcebook, destbook, objExcel, readfile, filesys, updatepivotrange, please, chart, preserve_formats, live, dest_Excel

to_filename = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\this.xlsx"

'see if Excel is open
On error resume next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")     
    if Err.Number<>0 then 
        Set dest_Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set destbook = dest_Excel.Workbooks.Open(to_filename,UpdateLinksCode)
        live = false
    else:
        Set destbook = GetObject(to_filename)
        Set dest_Excel = destbook.application
        live = true
    end if

On error goto 0
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
dest_Excel.DisplayAlerts = false

'Loop through sheets
for I = 1 To destbook.Worksheets.Count
    'loop through pivot tables
    for J = 1 to destbook.Worksheets(I).PivotTables.Count
        Set pt = destbook.Worksheets(I).PivotTables(J)
        'Error in attempting to get Pivot data source range
        Set rangeobj = dest_Excel.Evaluate(dest_Excel.ConvertFormula(pt.SourceData, -4150, 1))
        Set datasheet = destbook.Worksheets(rangeobj.Parent.Name)
        'only update pivot tables that have the sheet being updated referenced
        if sheet_name = datasheet.name then
            With datasheet
                If dest_Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                    lastrow = .Cells.Find("*", dest_Excel.Range("A1"), -4123, 2,  1, 2, False).Row
                    lastcol = .Cells.Find("*", dest_Excel.Range("A1"), -4123, 2,  2, 2, False).Column
                Else 
                    lastrow = 1
                    lastcol = 1
                End If
            End With
                Set sheet_range = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(1, 1), datasheet.Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

                With pt
                    .ChangePivotCache destbook.PivotCaches.Create(1, sheet_range, 3)
                    .PivotCache.Refresh
                    .HasAutoFormat = False
                    .SaveData = True
                    .PivotCache.RefreshOnFileOpen = True
                    .InGridDropZones = True
                    .RowAxisLayout 1
                End with
        End if
        destbook.Worksheets(I).PivotTables(J).RefreshTable
     Next
 Next

 if not live then
    destbook.save
    destbook.close
    dest_Excel.quit
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround that I'm not totally happy with, but it seems to work.  After testing to see if Excel is open, I test to see if the workbook window is visible.  Again, not a totally robust solution, but probably sufficient for my needs.

In the code below, live = "true" corresponds to scenario 1, "somewhat" to 2, and "false" to 3.

```
On error resume next
    Set dest_Excel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     if Err.Number<>0 then live = "false"
     Set destbook = GetObject(to_filename)
     Set dest_Excel = destbook.application
    'if workbook is visible and has the right path
    if dest_excel.Windows(destbook.name).visible = -1 and dest_excel.Windows(destbook.name).activesheet.parent.fullname = to_filename then
         live = "true"
    else
        if live <> "false" then live = "somewhat"
        set destbook = dest_Excel.Workbooks.Open(to_filename,UpdateLinksCode)
    end if
On error goto 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set x = GetObject("c:\file.xls")
```

Does what you want.

Your approach is wrong. You work with FILES not APPLICATIONS. Working with files COM rules apply and everything just works. Note, in the past, one did work with apps in COM, but no more.

Comment: But is there a way I can invoke application methods, i.e. Application.Evaluate(...) only using GetObject(file) if the file isn't already open?  There are several instances in my script where I rely on the Excel application, and I'm not sure how to code around them.

Comment: `workbook.application` that simple. So `set x = createObject("c:file.xls"):x.application.displayalerts`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. First, I get a run time error with `set x = createObject(file)`, presumably this should be `getObject`?  Secondly, I attempted to take `workbook.application` and then use functions like `application.evaluate`, but it only works if the file is already open in Excel or if I open it (i.e. with `Workbooks.Open(file)`); this is the crux of my question, and why simply using `GetObject` doesn't work.

Comment: Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Super.xls"):For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets:msgbox wsheet.name:mext:msgbox xlbook.application.displayalerts. This allows COM rules to apply.

Comment: So the point of this question is that I am calling the application object of my workbook, and at least these 2 commands result in an `Object required` error I first open the workbook (e.g. with `Workbooks.Open`), if it isn't already open: `.ChangePivotCache destbook.PivotCaches.Create(1, sheet_range, 3)`, `dest_Excel.Evaluate(dest_Excel.ConvertFormula(pt.SourceData, -4150, 1))`

Comment: `dest_Excel.Evaluate(dest_Excel.application.ConvertFormula(pt.SourceData, -4150, 1))` but evaluate is from a worksheet (not workbook) while convertformula is application. So I assume dest_excel is a worksheet not workbook?